# Write fixed-width fields to stream in Julia?

Tags: io, julia

In C++ you can do something like:

```
std::cout << setw(10) << left << x << setw(15) << left << t << std::endl;
```

to write two variables, `x` and `t`, to a stream, with a fixed column width.

How can I do this in Julia?

Comment: lpad() and rpad() may also be useful (I use these two very often).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@printf` gives you one way to do this:

```
@printf "%-10d %-15d\n" x t
```

[There is a quick reference](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/gcc/format_specs.html) to GCC's version of this syntax. Julia may not support all of it, though.

Comment: It would be nicer if something like `@printf "$x-10d"` worked (it doesn't).

Answer (score 1):

You could also use my `ScottPJones/StringUtils.jl` package.
(it's not registered, so you'd need to clone it).

```
using StringUtils
println(u"\%-10d(x) \%-15d(t)")
```

You might like some of the additional features it has compared to using the `@printf` macros.